# Gradual traffic routing to a new instance with AWS Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I use elastic beanstalk with autoscaling enabled.
When the autoscaling is triggered the new EC2 instance gets a full amount of live traffic immediately without having a chance to warm-up its cache.

Instance warmup described in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html#as-step-scaling-warmup) is not exactly what I need. As far as I understand it just allows to specify the time period that is needed for an instance before it's able to handle full amount of traffic.

Instead, is it possible to route traffic to the new instance in autoscaling group gradually? e.g. starting with 0.01% of the traffic that should be routed through this instance up to 100% over some specified period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no. An instance is either recieving traffic or its not.

I'd suggest a startup script on the instances that performs any warm-up tasks (curl or such). Then set your elb warm-up timeout based on a typical startup time factoring in time taken to start your application.

Comment: Is there any custom load balancing solution to solve this problem?

Comment: You might (possibly) find it in some high end hardware devices, or by rolling your own solution on top of ec2 instances - but i dont know of any cloud provider with your desired features as a service. If your use case is just warming up a beanstalk application your proposed solution seems unnecessarily complicated IMHO. A script will allow you to predictably (and thoroughly) warm up your application while 0.00% of your traffic is stuck waiting for a slow server to load. Using a small sample of your traffic to warm up a site will give inconsistent results, and a poor experience for that 0.01%.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advise!

Answer (score 1):

AWS introduced a "Slow start mode" to gradually shift traffic to a newly spun up instance to allow time for caches to be built, db connections established etc, just a few weeks after you asked this question.

Details of how to configure Slow Start Mode on your Auto scaling target group can be found here

[Auto Scaling Slow Start](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#slow-start-mode)